# My batch file isn't using the correct values despite being read

Tags: batch-file

I`m having issues with a batch file I have written to process a large amount of .wav music files with a tool. The encoded format is to have loop start and end points encoded within it.

```
@echo off
@echo -------CONVERSION---------
for /f "tokens=1-5" %%l in (test.txt) do (
  @echo %%n.wavを%%ni.fcoへ変換中です
  @echo %%o %%p
  set /a endloop1=%%o
  set /a endloop2=%%p
  set /a endloop=endloop1+endloop2
  @echo %endloop1% %endloop2% %endloop%
  contool -e -br 144 -loop %endloop1% %endloop% ed%%n.wav ed%%n.fco
```

And the test.txt file I`m reading values from in its entirety is

```
bgmtbl BGM_Title    7552 73664   4997136    
bgmtbl BGM_GameOver 7534 22464   4014400    
bgmtbl BGM_Midtown  7101 773184  3718720
bgmtbl BGM_Cross_1  7102 112838  5827154
```

Where the fourth and fifth values are the ones I need - the loop start point and loop length

for some reason the endloop values use the numbers from the last line of the text file over and over! e.g

```
7552.wavを7552i.fcoへ変換中です
73664 4997136
112838 5827154 5939992
your parametter doesn't satisfy under the condition
0<= loopstart(112838) <= loopend(5939992) < Total Sample(5118208) element=0/1

7534.wavを7534i.fcoへ変換中です
22464 4014400
112838 5827154 5939992
your parametter doesn't satisfy under the condition
0<= loopstart(112838) <= loopend(5939992) < Total Sample(4125696) element=0/1
```

etc

Please help, this is very perplexing!

Answer (score 3):

Another possibility:

```
@echo off &setlocal
for /f "tokens=1-5" %%l in (test.txt) do (
  echo %%n.wavを%%ni.fcoへ変換中です
  echo %%o %%p
  set /a endloop1=%%o
  set /a endloop2=%%p
  set /a endloop=%%o+%%p
)
echo %endloop1% %endloop2% %endloop%
```

Here you do not need `delayed expansion`. The first access to the `%variables%`  is after the end of the `for`    code block.

Comment: I tried this, but still had the same problem of using the last listed values 112838 and 5827154 over and over every iteration. Thank you for your suggestion though.

Comment: Ahh- I see what you mean: you can store it all in a line (answer by npocmaka) or line by line in an "array".

Answer (score 2):

```
@echo off
@echo -------CONVERSION---------
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
for /f "tokens=1-5" %%l in (test.txt) do (
  @echo %%n.wavを%%ni.fcoへ変換中です
  @echo %%o %%p
  set /a endloop1=%%o
  set /a endloop2=%%p
  set /a endloop=!endloop1!+!endloop2!
  @echo !endloop1! !endloop2! !endloop!
  contool -e -br 144 -loop !endloop1! !endloop! ed%%n.wav ed%%n.fco
)
```

More info : http://www.robvanderwoude.com/variableexpansion.php